# Why do parent layouts not have access to registered services when a nested layout is introduced (Using Asp.NET Core 5 using MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Using `@inject IFooService FooService` in any main layout page works fine.  However, if I have a nested layout file, those services can no longer be found.  `HttpContext` is reverted to `DefaultHttpContext` and the .cshtml's `'Context'` is null in the top layout page.

**This works:**

- ```
   Main Layout (services can be injected here)
  ```
- ```
        * Some content page.
  ```

**This does not work:**

- ```
   Main Layout (services CANNOT be found here any longer)
  ```
- ```
        Sub Layout (services CAN be found here now)
  ```
- ```
             Some content page
  ```

Comment: Can you show us the structure of your cshtml about the layout page? And if show your sample code for us to test (without any sensitive info), maybe we can help you better.

Comment: I have some funky stuff with async that's killing HttpContext.  I'm going to clear that off and see if the problem still exists.  Will update shortly.

Comment: Confirmed - async was messing part of it up and was dropping HttpContext.